# Apache Cassandra Time Zone Issue

Tags: datetime, hadoop, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to move the data from MSSQL to **cassandra** using talent, But am getting the **timezone** issue because MSSQL in CST timezone where as Cassandra having the timezone Etc/UTC.

Tried Changing the below config file

```
Location: /opt/apache-cassandra-3.9/conf/
```

File: `cqlshrc.sample`

Changed from : **timezone = Etc/UTC to :timezone = CST**

But still the cqlsh shows the UTC timestamp

```
cqlsh>  select toTimestamp(now()) from system.local;
```

### system.totimestamp(system.now())

```
2017-01-04 06:38:45.645000+0000
```

I am using apache cassandra 3.9

So please some one help me to proceed in this.

Comment: By default cqlshrc file is in the ~/.cassandra directory. Set your timezone option without comment by removing semicolon ; https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshUsingCqlshrc.html?hl=cqlshrc

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the `pytz` module installed? You might have missed the following warning when starting cqlsh:

```
[me@centos bin]$ ./cqlsh
Warning: Timezone defined and 'pytz' module for timezone conversion not installed. Timestamps will be displayed in UTC timezone.
```

Also, it might be that you have to specify the timezone in the area/location format. Try and give `America/Chicago` a go.

Either way, this is only about the display of the timestamps. Cassandra does not store any timezone information with dates/timestamps. They are always stored in UTC.

Comment: Where do I find the  area/location table?

Comment: @quangkid, you can find it on Wikipedia, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones